# Planescape PC with high ability scores

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

I am doing a new character with 35 PB system.

It's the Planescape setting and we're using almost every source of D&D (Dragon magazines, all manuals and so on), but not with every single Race or Class.

I like high ability scores values, still I am not looking for an OP build (I'd like an efficent one, but not OP). My current character has 94 ability points but has died like 4 times in a row, so it's really not OP for us.

The first idea is this one:

Orog + Half Dragon (LA +2/+3  that will be +1/+3 at lvl 6 and +0/+3 at lvl 9)
+14 str +0 dex +2 con +2 int -2 wis +4 cha.

Base abilities 16 Str 13 Dex 10 Int 10 Wis 12 Cha

Final abilities:

- Str 30
- Dex 13
- Con 18
- Int 12
- Wis 10
- Cha 16

He should be one-way gladiator that will fight with notbora, then he will pick 2 Prestige Classes (gonna think about them)

The other idea is wildren/half-troll (LA +0/+4) but still, I don't know what to do with that.

Any idea?

It seems like I have got clear mind about what I am going to do, but actually I need help for Feats and Equipment that can allow me to maximize my ability points and/or help me in hard situations, and of course maybe some suggestions about base class.

I'd like to show to you the races and classes but it's all in Italian (my native language).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! We’re a dedicated Q&A where you can get authoritative answers to your specific questions, and we’d love to help answer any you have—but we can’t really help with broad idea generation. To help, we really need you to describe in a lot of detail what you’re looking for—you say “It seems like I have got clear mind about what I am going to do,” but it’s not clear *for us*—we can’t see what it is you want, so we can’t really help you. You might be better off with a discussion forum to determine what idea you’re going with, and we could help with the details, perhaps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the corrections you made to my question. Well.. actually you are right, it is a "big and generic" question i have here. so you suggest to move my question elsewhere and then, after i have got a solid character, i could come here to ask something more specific?

Comment: Hello, I'll give you an upvote, so you will be closer to access chat where you certainly will have an easier time to add details. I voted to close this question, but once you can provide the details you can apply that and we can reopen it. - from review

Comment: Yeah, we have a [decent list of discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563) that might be better places to sort out the basic idea, and then once you have that, we can help more here. As Akixkisu mentions, one of the discussion forums we recommend is our own [Chat], which you should now (between our upvotes) have access to, so you could do that, or else you could check out one of the traditional forums for this. Giantitp or Minmax is probably best for 3.5e?